# DSolve struggles with simple differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the set of differential equations

```
equations = {  f[x, y] + (x - y) D[f[x, y], y] == 0, 
               D[f[x, y], x] == -D[f[x, y], y]        }
```

If we try to solve this set in one command:

```
DSolve[equations, f, {x, y}]
```

the routine fails and simply returns back the input.

However, if we approach it in smaller steps -- first solving one of the equations:

```
solution1 = DSolve[equations[[1]], f, {x, y}][[1]]
```

> {f -> Function[{x, y}, (-x + y) C[1][x]]}

and then the second equation:

```
solution2 = DSolve[equations[[2]] /. solution1, C[1], x][[1]]
```

> {C[1] -> Function[{x}, C[2]]}

we readily find a result, so that the full solution can be summarized as

```
f[x,y]/.solution1/.solution2
```

> (-x + y) C[2]

It seems weird to me that `DSolve[equations, f, {x, y}]` does not return this result right away, since obtaining it is so simple. Perhaps I am not using the correct syntax? Is there a way to make Mathematica return the final result in one single step? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You switched from a PDE to an ODE in your by-hand solution. I'm not sure `DSolve` is that clever.  I think it disqualifies this from being a "simple" problem.  Generically, this sort of problem doesn't have a solution, I think. Even here, the dimension of the solution space is degenerate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does that mean `DSolve` cannot handle any PDEs at all?

Comment: Do you mean like `solution1`? -- Or do you mean an arbitrary pair of first-order linear PDEs? (You're asking for `DSolve` to find the intersection of the solution spaces of the individual PDEs, which is usually just the zero function, I think, except in special cases.)

Comment: What's the source or application of this system?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just encountered this system while solving for some functions of x,y with specific transformation properties. I guess I got lucky that the system was solvable in this fashion.

Comment: My guess is the transformation properties probably led to the coincidence.

Comment: Looks like you have 2 pde's with one unknown, `f[x,y]`.  It's not a surprise `DSolve`  considers that to be uncool. Neither of the pde's could be taken to be a boundary condition.